# How to checkout older version of google-api-dotnet-client

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I just downloaded latest copy of google-api-dotnet-client from url (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) and it shows version 1.2.4819.34602 .

I am using google Drive .net API library which I have downloaded from URL http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API . This google drive library refrences Google APIs library which has version 1.2.4737.25316 . When I try to reference the latest API, it throws many errors like

```
 Error > The type or namespace name 'ServiceRequest' could not be found 
 (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I need to change some lines of code in the SOURCE FILE of google-api-dotnet-client which is referenced by GOOGLE DRIVE. So to do that I will require to CHECKOUT an older version of google-api-dotnet-client i.e. version 1.2.4737.25316 . How can I do that?

Thanks
Sujit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made some changes in the library (which is still in development, and will be published next week). The new code will not work with the generated API you are trying to download.

My advice to you is to clone our repository and then update it to the state of the API (1.2.4737):
hg update 20121220-1.2.4737-beta

Then you will be able to compile and make the changes you need.

Good luck

And I'm just curious, what are you trying to do? Is something missing in the library that we should add in next releases?

Comment: Just stumble across this, and on the off chance you read it, it appears the removal of services has broken the Google+ API, and frankly, I'm not smart enough to know how to clone/update etc to get around the issue.